# How to add Solr PECL extension into lampp (xampp) stack

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, pecl, lampp

Is it possible to add PECL extensions into a lampp stack? If so, how can it be done?

I am specifically interested in http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php extension.

EDIT: when installing this extension using:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/pecl install -f solr
```

everything seams to go as it should except at the end:

```
checking for cURL support... yes, shared
checking for cURL in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
        easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl/
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/solr/configure --enable-solr=yes --enable-solr-debug=no --with-curl=/opt/lampp/bin --with-libxml-dir=/usr' failed
```

From what I understand this should mean that it simply needs to find the correct curl location which I specify in the install when it asks as 'opt/lampp/bin'

Does this mean that it can't be done without recompiling php using a different curl package? Is this even possible with a lampp stack or do I have to now build my own?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [PHP: Installation of PECL extensions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).

Also take a look at the requirements of the SOLR extension module: http://docs.php.net/solr.requirements

Comment: So the same technique applies to a lampp stack as it does to a separately built stack?

Comment: Yes, in both cases it's: either find a compatible binary .so/.dll or compile the extension module yourself. phpinfo() can tell you which ./configure switches have been used to build the php-core.

Comment: @user103219 I've got the same error .. I cannot understand how you guys solved this issue. Could you explain it easier? Thanks